# Proving the sines and cosines of the special angles for the unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

Given the definitions of sine and cosine (opp/hyp and adj/hyp respectively) how do the special angle identities arise? That is to say, how can there be a fraction with 2 in the denominator when the denominator (hypotenuse) is 1 by definition?

Comment: Because adj and opp are both <1 in those cases

Comment: [This link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53929.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following graphic.
[image]

In each balloon, blue line is exactly three times as long as the red  line. No matter how much I blow up (or deflate) the balloon, that relationship will never change (except of course when I blow up the balloon to the point where I no longer have red and blue lines, but pink and celeste ones instead).

[image]

Similarly, one need not have a right triangle with an hypotenuse of $1$ in order to calculate trigonometric ratios. All that is required is that we use a triangle that is similar to said triangle. For if the hypotenuse is always twice as long as the opposite leg, then $\sin A$ is always $1/2$. In such a situation it may be convenient to use an equilateral triangle whose sides equal $2$, split it in half, and then calculate the $\sin 30^{\circ}$.

[image]